# Possible lose connection when running async tcp client written in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, tcp, client

Here's my stress test code written in Nodejs, trying to make the server take over 30000+ concurrent connections.

server:

```
var net = require('net');

var clients = 0;

net.createServer(function (sock) {
    ++clients;
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort + ', now online: ' + clients);
    sock.on('close', function () {
       --clients;
       console.log('CLOSED, now online: ' + clients);
    });
}).listen(7000);
```

client:

```
var net = require('net');

var clients = 0;

for (idx = 0; idx < 30000; ++idx) {
    var client = new net.Socket();

    client.connect(7000, 'localhost', function () {
        console.log('connected ' + (++clients));
    });

    client.on('close', function () {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
}
```

when running, output from the client side seems normal, the number goes all the way up to 30000. But for the server side, the number goes up to around 10000+ at the most.

So I wrote a traditional tcp client in C language. and this time both client & server look fine(exactly as what's expected).

btw, no socket close is reported in these tests.

Does anyone have same experience?